# URL in MVC 5 asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pdf.js

I am trying to user PDF.js to display pdf on the MVC 5 application.

The problem is it is taking the file name through URL

```
localhost:32557/Viewer/PDFViewer?filename=thepdffile.pdf
```

The problem is I am redirecting to the PDFViewer from another method based on the type of viewer

```
case 5:
   return RedirectToAction("PDFViewer?file=/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf", new { id = viewerId});
```

and the url I am getting is

```
localhost:32557/Viewer/PDFViewer%3ffile%3d/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf
```

Also I am getting error with this URL

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
```

Can you please help me on this

Comment: `RedirectToAction("PDFViewer", new { file = "/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf", id = viewerId}")`? What do you expect the redirected URL to look like?

Comment: it should be `localhost:32557/Viewer/PDFViewer?file=/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf`

Comment: Then omit `id = viewerId`, it's not clear what that's supposed to do in the first place. You're redirecting to the _action_ `PDFViewer?file=/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf`, which does not exist. The action is `PDFViewer`, the file is a parameter.

Comment: `RedirectToAction` redirects to a specified *action*, with parameters specified separately from the action name. If you just want to redirect to an URL, use `Redirect`. So, if `/Viewer/PDFViewer` is actually an action method under your control (e.g. `ActionResult ViewerController.PDFViewer(string file)`), you should `RedirectToAction` after reading the documentation for it. If not, you should use `Redirect`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be something more like RedirectToAction("PDFViewer", new { file = "/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf"}); Then on your PDFViewer action it would have a parameter of... (string file)

Comment: the problem is i am not taking the parameter in my controller. instead PDF.js is using it. and it wan't the url to be like `localhost:32557/Viewer/PDFViewer?file=/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pd‌​f`

Comment: @bzlm  I have used `Redirect` instead of `RedirectToAction` and is working as expected. thanks

Comment: @Iftikhar - Please post that as your answer so others may find this information helpful (and so contributors don't waste their time looking at questions that there is already an answer to).

Comment: @Iftikhar would you happen to have source code for your PDFViewer page?  Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved with help of @bzlm's comment to use `Redirect` instead of `RedirectToAction`.

so earlier I was using

```
return RedirectToAction("PDFViewer?file=/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf", new { id = viewerId})
```

instead of this I could have used

```
return Redirect(baseUrl+"Viewer/PDFViewer?file=/source/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf")
```

`baseUrl` is a string variable holding `localhost:32557/`